# Transfer free Play Store apps to another account

Tags: applications, google-play-store

On my tablet I installed a few free apps from Play Store using my account and then created a new google account removing the old, but now every time I visit the Play Store although I see which apps are installed, under "My Apps" is empty. How can I transfer the applications to a new account?

Comment: Sorry, but you can't...  Remove and reinstall each app on the new account.

Answer (score 0):

Re-install them. Google is not flexible in that way.